# Are object methods faster than global functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, optimization

### The Issue

Cannot believe I could not find anything on this around the net, maybe I am searching for the wrong thing...

There is probably little or no difference at all, but as I am trying to optimize my code as best I possibly can, I feel it is worth asking.

Very simply, I would like to know whether defining and running a method in an object processes faster than defining and running a function globally.

### Examples

**Consider this:**

```
(function($){  
    $.fn.test = function() {  
        // do something here
    };  
})(jQuery);
```

**And this:**

```
function test(){
    // do something here
}
```

### My Question

Which of the above is faster and why? If there is no difference in speed then which would you advise using?

Thanks in advance

### UPDATE 1

As it may be relevant, I feel it is necessary to explain why I am asking this question. I have a library that I have written over the years that contains a large variety of functions. As there are so many of them, I want to know whether they would run faster if I was to extend the jQuery object, or keep them as they are?

Comment: To me a global function would have less overhead since there is no object to deal with.  I may be completely wrong though :)

Comment: @JonTaylor Even if the object is there anyway?

Comment: Not sure, if the object already exists then possibly not.  I am no expert with javascript optimization though.

Comment: @JonTaylor With a server side language such as PHP then the answer would obviously be the object methods because they are pre-compiled, but I am unsure about this with javascript

Comment: It depends on what is do something. By your example on its own, 1st one uses jquery and 2nd one uses vanilla javascript so 2nd one will be obviously faster.

Comment: @specialscope thank you for your comment, I will update my question with a clear example of why I am asking this as your comments may be different :-)

Comment: Did you try to profile your two examples ? For instance Chrome offer you a profiling tool (`CTRL + SHIFT + I > Profiles`). Profile and see what's works best in your case. Don't forget to test on other browsers you target. 

IMO, I think methods can be *called* faster because they are located in a **smaller** namespace. Global functions are located in the global namespace and you don't usually imagine all the many functions living there ...

Comment: @specialscope The first one is in the jQuery namespace, but it's not "using jQuery". I assume "do something" will be the same in both cases, so if that uses jQuery the performance hit will be the same.

Comment: The best way to answer questions like is X faster than Y is to test yourself. I'd recomend http://jsperf.com/ for testing it cross browsers. Just set it up and run with several browsers. Also ask friends on different machines and Op.Systems to do the same and voila.

Comment: As @Eduardo says in his clever comment, add a test to jsperf.com and send us the link. I have a some browsers on machine for running your tests.

Comment: @Stephan probably not a very good example, but this should work http://jsfiddle.net/YMSrz/

Comment: @BenCarey Check this test : http://jsperf.com/global-context-or-class-context/3 (Chrome 17.0.963 + FF 10.0.2 + IE6). With a noop test() function, Global context clearly "wins".

Comment: @Stephan Thank you very much, that is very interesting. I would definitely have thought that the class would be faster as it would be in PHP. I wonder if it would be faster with just a normal namespace, not jQuery. I will try :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In theory, you just need to count the number of objets that must be searched to determine which will be faster. Variables are resolved against the scope chain, the script engine must first search the function's execution context, then the outer contexts, and finally the global context.

Property resolution must first find the object on the scope chain, then the property on the object or its `[[Prototype]]` chain.

But in practice, compiler optimisation means the above simplistic analysis is will be wrong as often as it is right, and also deliver different results in different browsers for different cases.

Generally, such optimisations deliver minuscule changes in performance and should not be considered purely for performance reasons. Design objects and methods for whatever makes sense for your application architecture, ease of maintenance and logical grouping.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph. Premature optimization is often wasted effort.

Comment: +1 Brilliant answer, thank you :-) The reason I am doing this is for logical grouping, so I think I will probably just extend the jQuery object

Comment: @BenCarey Unless they're jQuery plugins, why not create your own namespace for these functions?

Comment: @Alnitak Yes I know, this is what I will be doing. It is only because some of these will be jQuery plugins and some of them will be general functions. I will probably add most of them to my own namespace :-)

Answer (score 3):

I have done this research about a year ago and I can say that it's faster to use `this.test()`.

But it depends on what do you need. I don't recommend to add unnecessary functions to the jQuery, if you only want to make an object for specific "widget".

Simple object oriented usage:

```
function Car(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Car.prototype.startEngine = function() {
    // Start the engine...
};

Car.prototype.drive = function() {
    this.startEngine();

    // Switch the lights, fasten your seatbelt...
};


// create a new car
var bmw = new Car('BMW');

// Drive the car
bmw.drive();
```

Another thing what you have to understand is the environment (I hope you understand what I mean). It's better to make a fresh space of variables and functions, so there are not too many variables/functions to look for. Immagine that as a list - if it's smaller, it's faster to find things in it.
So, you make a fresh "space":

```
(function(){
    // Your fresh space.
})();
```

JavaScript will try to find things in "local" space and then it will try to find things in global space. Immagine it like this:

```
|- global
     |- function aaa
     |- function bbb
     |- var myName
     |- your local space
           |- function ccc
           |- function aaa  It will not overwrite global function with the same name
           |- var someVariable
```

As you can see, in "local space" there are only 3 items, so it's faster to find things.

It's faster to call semi-global functions in local "spaces". And, if you want to do some object oriented stuff, it's better and faster to extend the "object".

**UPDATE**
If you want to tidy up your function library, then you could group them inside an object. I don't think it would be slower.

```
var lib = {
    foo: function() {},
    bar: function() {},
    test: function() {}
};

lib.test();
```

Comment: adding functions to the prototype of a constructor function object is not the same as adding functions as _properties_ of an object for namespacing purposes .

Answer (score 2):

When you want to know which of two approach is faster the best way is to profile them. This would give you the result pertaining to your code and not a generic concept.

In my opinion, you shouldn't be optimizing it for speed, but for maintainability and richness of the API. From your question

```
function test(){
    // do something here
}
```

is in the global scope which is always bad. You should ideally be placing those method in a namespace and the sample 1 in your questions does that as part of jQuery namespace.